# Problem with data.table ifelse behavior

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I am trying to calculate a simple ratio using data.table. Different files have different tmax values, so that is why I need `ifelse`. When I debug this, the dt looks good. The `tmaxValue` is a single value (the first "t=60" encountered in this case), but `t0Value` is all of the "t=0" values in dt.

```
summaryDT <- calculate_Ratio(reviewDT[,list(Result, Time), by=key(reviewDT)])

calculate_Ratio <- function(dt){
tmaxValue <- ifelse(grepl("hhep", inFile, ignore.case = TRUE), 
    dt[which(dt[,Time] == "t=240min"),Result],
    ifelse(grepl("hlm",inFile, ignore.case = TRUE), 
        dt[which(dt[,Time] == "t=60"),Result],
        dt[which(dt[,Time] == "t=30"),Result]))
t0Value <- dt[which(dt[,Time] == "t=0"),Result]
return(dt[,Ratio:=tmaxValue/t0Value])
}
```

What I am getting out is the`Result` for `tmaxValue` divided by all of the `Result`'s for all of the `t0Value`'s, but what I want is a single ratio for each unique `by`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ...Could you clarify what your data is? It seems to be a `data.table` since you use `Ratio:=tmaxValue/t0Value]`? A small reproducible example would be good.

Comment: +1 For Tommy's request for reproducible data. Also, please edit to simplify each of the `dt[which(dt[,Time] == "t=240min"),Result]` to `dt[Time=="t=240min",Result]`. Even then, we don't like `==` in `i` (see introduction vignette about _vector scanning_) but at least we're making progress ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, but typically using `ifelse` is the wrong thing to do.

Try using `if(...) ... else ...` instead.

`ifelse(test, yes, no)` acts very weird: It produces a result with the **attributes** and **length** from `test` and the values from `yes` or `no`.
...so in your case you should get something without attributes and of length one - and that's probably not what you wanted, right?

[UPDATE] ...Hmm or maybe it is since you say that `tmaxValue` is a single value... 
Then the problem isn't in calculating `tmaxValue`? Note that `ifelse` is still the wrong tool for the job...